# TeXnicCenter & MiKTeX – "directory where the executable is located"?

Tags: errors, installing, miktex, texniccenter

I have a 64-bit System running Windows 7. I installed MiKTeX and then tried to install the TeXnicCenter editor.

All went well until I clicked on the TeXnicCenter icon on my desktop and was asked

> Enter the full path of the directory where the executable (latex, tex, etc) of your TeX-distribution is located

I answered `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXnicCenter` - which is where the TeXnicCenter download went! But there is a problem - the error message is as follows:

> The application 'LaTeX' has not been found in the directory of your TeX-distribution is located
>
> Please enter the directory where the executiable files (`tex.exe`, `latex.exe`, etc) are located.

I am beginning to wonder if there is something else I should have downloaded other than the TeXnicCenter system?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11):

[MiKTeX](http://miktex.org/) and [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) are two different things. The former is a distribution of TeX that includes a bunch of packages as well as the executables `latex.exe`, `pdflatex.exe`, `tex.exe`, etc. The latter is an editor that provides a front end to the distribution. You should point TeXnicCenter to where you installed *MiKTeX*, not TeXnicCenter itself.

On my machine, running TeXnicCenter on Windows 7 with [TeX Live 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) (yet another distribution of TeX), my setup looks like this:

[image: TeXnicCenter building profiles]

These building profiles (I have a bunch of them, as you can see from the list on the left) are set up when you first start TeXnicCenter. The "Path to the (La)TeX compiler" is the location of `latex.exe` on your machine. Depending on where you installed MiKTeX, that's where `latex.exe` resides. I'm guessing it would be somewhere in:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\2.9\bin\
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX\2.9\bin\
```

depending on whether you installed a 64-bit version of `2.9`.

---

**Edit**: I may be wrong in my path assumption above. @doncherry has pointed out that this may in fact be

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\
```

Goes to show the installation structure of different installation may be noticeably different.

Comment: It used to be C:\...\Miktex 2.x\miktex\bin has this changed in the 2.9 version? (Not that it matters because it is sufficient to search in which folder latex.exe is but just for correctness)

Comment: @MartinH: I may have been incorrect in my path specification. It stems from the installation folders offered by TeX Live, which has a `.\texlive\<version>\bin` structure rather than what MiKTeX offers. At least it guides to the appropriate location.

Comment: For me it was automatically installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin. This seems to be the default.

Answer (score 6):

I think the most reliable way is to go to MikTex console->setting->Directories->"Links to the executables have been installed in"

Somehow mine is

C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything that Werner said except the path. I have the same setup as Peter (Win7 64bit), and my path is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin
```

The output profile looks like this (I have several non-standard profiles as well):

[image]

So, quick overview:

MiKTeX, TeX Live = distributions of **LaTeX**, i.e. "the LaTeX system itself"

TeXnicCenter, TeXworks, ... = **editors** set up for LaTeX

You might have come across proTeXt as well; this is a bundle containing, among other things, a LaTeX distribution (MiKTeX) and a LaTeX editor (TeXnicCenter).

Comment: One correction: If your MikTex is a 64 bit version, then the directory is:
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\2.9\bin\x64 Don't ignore the last part, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: For me (using a 64-bit version of MikTeX with TeXnicCenter) the info provided by Yaa-See was the key to getting everything up and running. Please don't delete that comment, it IS exactly the answer I was looking for! To the moderator -feel free to delete this post.

Answer (score 1):

MiKTeX changed it to:

```
%LocalAppData%\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64
```

if you choose "Install Miktex only for me" as recommended https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex

[image]